# How to show that $N(AB)^{\perp}\subseteq N(B)^{ \perp}$ if $A, B \in Mn$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If $Bx=0$ then $(AB)(X)=0$. So $N(B) \subseteq N(AB)$. This implies that $(N(AB))^{\perp} \subseteq N(B)^{\perp}$ by definition of orthogonal complement.

[Let $y \in (N(AB))^{\perp}$. If $x \in N(B)$ then $x \in N(AB)$ so $y$ is orthogonal to $x$. Hence $y \in (N(B))^{\perp}$].